# C++ Linker Error - Defining things twice

Tags: c++, header, linker

To start off, I'm kind of new to instantiation files, headers, and source files.
I'm trying to get my code to compile, but I keep hitting a linker error where it says that I'm defining something twice.

I have 6 Files:
 - Instantiation.cpp Lab5.cpp Students.cpp Queue.cpp Students.h Queue.h

Instantiation:

```
#include "Students.cpp"
#include "Lab5.cpp"
#include "Queue.cpp"

template class Queue<int>;
template class QueueNode<int>;
template class Queue < Students* >;
template class QueueNode < Students* >;
```

Lab5:

```
#include "Queue.h"
#include "Students.h"
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main(){
Queue <Students*> studentQueue;
Queue <int> integerQueue;
return 0;
}
```

Students.cpp:

```
#include "Students.h"
Students::Students(){
}
void Students::printStudent(){
}
```

Queue.cpp:

```
#include "Queue.h"
template <class DataType>
Queue<DataType>::Queue(int i){
i = queueSize;
}
template <class DataType>
Queue<DataType>::~Queue(){
}
template <class DataType>
void Queue<DataType>::enQueue(const DataType){
}
template <class DataType>
DataType Queue<DataType>::deQueue(){
return 0;
}
template <class DataType>
DataType Queue<DataType>::topQueue() const {
return 0;
}
template <class DataType>
bool Queue<DataType>::isEmpty() const {
return true;
}
template <class DataType>
bool Queue<DataType>::isFull() const{
return true;
}
```

Students.h:

```
#ifndef STUDENTS_H
#define STUDENTS_H
class Students{
public:
char lastName[20];
char firstName[20];
int ID; // ID
Students(); // constr
void printStudent(); // print info
};
#endif
```

Queue.h:

```
#ifndef QUEUE_H
#define QUEUE_H

template <class DataType>
class QueueNode {
public:
    DataType data;
    QueueNode<DataType> *next;
};
template <class DataType>
class Queue {
private:
    QueueNode<DataType> *front;
    QueueNode<DataType> *back;
    int queueSize; // size of a Queue
    int queueCnt; // elem count in a Queue
public:
    Queue(int = 10); // class constr. - initialize vars
    ~Queue(); // class destructor - remove all mem space used by queue elems
    void enQueue(const DataType); // add item to back of queue
    DataType deQueue(); // remove first item from queue and return its value
    DataType topQueue() const; // return the value of the first item in the queue
    bool isEmpty() const; // returns true if there are no elems in the queue
    bool isFull() const; // returns true if no system mem for a new queue node
};
#endif
```

Here's the output:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/WxbRd.png

Please, help.
I don't really get why it thinks I'm defining anything twice.

Comment: You shouldn't be `#include`ing .cpp files, only .h (header) files.

Comment: Put template classes entirely in the header file and be done with it. Too much hassle otherwise.

Comment: Well, I really appreciate the answer, but I didn't think it was strictly impermissible. I have Instantiation.cpp to link my templated .cpp files @Steve

Comment: @NeilKirk, how exactly do I do that?

Comment: `template <class DataType> class QueueNode { void myfunc() { CODE } };`

Comment: @NeilKirk , So the explicit declarations in Instantiation.cpp should be removed? I have that snippet already, I thought. Sorry if I'm not getting it.

Comment: Yes. All queue in just one header file. That's the easiest way to handle templates.

Comment: OK, last q: sorry :$ So, I #include Lab5 in Instantiation.cpp, but remove the other #include's for Queue and Students?

Comment: You need to @ me or I won't get the notification. Remove the file Instantiation.cpp entirely.

Comment: @NeilKirk, Sorry, a little new to this... And okay, that makes sense. Also, on a side note... What was I doing wrong if I were to say, want to keep the Instantiation.cpp file? Because, my teacher is fairly anal retentive and will probably get mad if I don't include that file...

Comment: Was the file empty apart from some include statements?

Comment: Is this an exercise to figure out how to get templates to work when split between header and source files??

Comment: @NeilKirk I posted everything in that file. And, not exactly. It's just a tool he wants us to know how to do. It's a basic concept, but he wants us to separate and have one file to link all the templated .cpp files... He more wants us to be able to use templates and queue implementation on a linked list

Comment: If he wanted you to implement the templates one way, he may not like that you did it another way. But this is the way I make most of my templates.

Comment: If you put the template entirely in the header, there's no need for Instantiation.cpp any more.

Comment: @NeilKirk On our last project, I had to use header guards on a .cpp file and include the instantiation file on a couple of my files to make it automagically work. But that was from the help of my friend... I frankly didn't understand why it was able to compile...

Comment: Yeah, @NeilKirk . Is there any way I could maintain my Instantiation file and make this work? Like, would you know how to fix it? (even if it's a little messy)

Comment: I would have two header files. One for the basic class definition, and the second with the full functions in it. Then any source files which create an instance of the object includes the second file, but other source files which only use the object include the smaller first header file.

Comment: @NeilKirk I guess what I'm trying to say is that he wants me to keep the same number of files, headers and source files respectively... What line or lack of lines in my code is causing it to link twice?

Comment: I believe it is including student.cpp as Student is not a template class. Don't include source files which contain non-templated things.

Comment: @NeilKirk , okay... (And, you mean I shouldn't include source files that dont contain templated things?) so if I were to remove #include "Students.cpp", that would be a fix? When I do that, that removes about two of my errors. However, I still get error LNK2005: _main already defined in Instantiation.obj

Comment: You are including a source file which contains main. I mean very exactly: don't include source files which contain things which are not part of a template.

Comment: @NeilKirk , OK, sorry. And, I'm sorry for going through such a hassle.. So what do I need to do with that file, exactly? Students.cpp and Lab5.cpp both are non-templated I believe. But, Queue.cpp is...(I think)... However, if I remove those, I'm stll left w/ more errors.

Comment: The only source file it should include is for queue, but it may need to include student header file, as it uses student class.

Comment: @NeilKirk , I feel like I'm being such a bother... I'm really sorry... This is just confusing to me. When I comment out the include statement for Lab5.cpp, it still gives me errors for defining things twice. http://prntscr.com/6gxeq5 , but if I comment out the include statement for Students, I get http://prntscr.com/6gxf05

Comment: Don't worry I am happy to help :) But I am going to bed soon. What do you have in instancate.cpp now?

Comment: @NeilKirk I have http://prntscr.com/6gxh9v

Comment: You need to include student header file.

Comment: @NeilKirk , like this: http://prntscr.com/6gxi7b ?

Comment: oh my god it compiles... ur a savior LOL @NeilKirk thank youuuuuu

Comment: Next for you is to figure out why that fixes it!